# firebase 3 - goOffline API method missing?

Tags: firebase

I can't seem to find the goOffline/goOnline methods (available in v2 API) in the new v3 API?

If it has been deprecated, how do we go about disconnecting users so that they do not consume active websocket connections?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `goOnline()` and `goOffline()` methods to explicitly manage the connection are still there. They are part of the `FirebaseDatabase` class.

See the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#public-methods).

Note the above points to the Android documentation, since you didn't specify a technology. But the method has the same name and will be on the equivalent class on all other platforms too.

Comment: Thanks so much for the head up. I completely missed this (and the obvious search bar in the new documentation).  I'm using the web API and the method can be called like: firebase.database().goOffline();

Thanks again for the help. :)